# Why does the $\Delta \vec{v}$ of an object travelling in uniform circular motion always point to the center of the path?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

When finding the relationship between the acceleration of the particles and the constant magnitude of the velocity, we were given the following diagram:

[image]

It's said that "The vector $\Delta \vec{v}$ always points toward the center of the circle, no matter where we choose points $P_1$ and $P_2$.

How do we know that $\Delta \vec{v}$ ALWAYS points toward the center?? Is there any mathematical proof to back up this statement? It would be nice if anyone could explain both the mathematical proof and the physical intuition for that!

Comment: It's probably important to specify *from where* the vector $\Delta \vec{v}$ is pointing if you want to know *to where* it is pointing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the velocity vectors at the two endpoints on an arc of the orbit and slide them along the arc to the center of the arc. Draw $\Delta \vec v$. You'll get a diagram like the inset diagram.  Since the vectors have equal magnitude, you'll find that (by symmetry) $\Delta \vec v$ points to the center. [It's an isosceles triangle with base $\Delta \vec v$, which is perpendicular to the height, which is the direction of the velocity-vector at the center of the arc.]

(You can take the limit of a smaller arc.)

This is consistent with the fact that the
infinitesimal change in the velocity vector ($\ d\vec v\ $)
is parallel to the acceleration vector, which points in the direction of the net force on the orbiting particle.

This may be a little fancy but....

constant speed implies
$$\mbox{constant}=\vec v\cdot \vec v.$$
Take the time-derivative, to show that $$\vec a\ \bot\ \vec v.$$

Since $\vec v$ is tangential to the circle, what does this tell you about $\vec a$?

Comment: The derivative of the velocity at any given point indeed points towards the center.  For a finite difference in velocities "pointing towards the center" is not well defined.  Where is the starting point of the difference vector? This is not associated to a specific point on the trajectory.

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining what's the physical meaning for sliding the 2 vectors to the *center* of the arc?

Comment: To perform the difference of two vectors, the tails of the vectors need to coincide. Appealing to symmetry, not preferring one end to the other, the middle point of the arc seems appropriate. The middle point of the arc, in some sense represents a family of ever shortening arcs centered at that point. That's what your diagram shows.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can see it if you obtain the components of the velocity  in $(x~,y)~$ system

\begin{align*}
&\text{Position vector }\\
 &\vec{r}=r\,\begin{bmatrix}
               \cos(\varphi) \\
               \sin(\varphi)\\
             \end{bmatrix}\\\\
&\text{Velocity vector }\\             
&\vec{v}=v\,\begin{bmatrix}
               -\sin(\varphi) \\
               \cos(\varphi)\\
             \end{bmatrix}\\\\
&\text{thus}\\
&\vec{v}_1=\vec{v}(\varphi=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)\\
&\vec{v}_2=\vec{v}(\varphi=\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)\\              
&\vec{v}_2-\vec{v}_1=-v\,
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 \\
  2\,\sin(\theta) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}